# How to load a 16-bits/channel RGB(A) image with PIL?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to load a 16 bits colors RGBA image with PIL.

I downloaded the image pnggrad16rgba.png from the following link:
https://www.fnordware.com/superpng/samples.html
[image]
I checked that it has indeed 16 bits per pixel's color channel:

[image: screenshot of file properties in Windows Explorer]

But then when I try to load the data in PIL, I get **`uint8`** data:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> import numpy
>>> im = Image.open("D:/pnggrad16rgba.png")
>>> arr = numpy.array(im)
>>> arr.dtype
dtype('uint8')
>>> arr[0, 0]
array([  0,   0, 255, 255], dtype=uint8)
```

Is there a way to access the 16 bits data without downcasting it to `uint8` with `PIL`?

If not, what other library could handle this?

Comment: I would imagine that Pil would support various bits natively, see the docs. But, in the meantime, have you tried setting the data type during the array creation eg arr = numpy.array(im, dtype=np.uint16) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**PIL** doesn't support multi-channel 16-bit/channel images - see [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes). I would suggest you use **OpenCV** with the `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` flag like this:

```
import cv2                                                                                               

# Load image as 16-bits per channel, 4 channels
BGRA = cv2.imread('pnggrad16rgba.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) 

# Check channels and depth
print(BGRA.dtype, BGRA.shape)                                                                                                
dtype('uint16')
(600, 600, 4)
```

Be aware that your image will be in `BGRA` order, not `RGBA`, because **OpenCV** is... well, **OpenCV**.

If you need to, you can get from BGRA to RGBA using

```
RGBA = cv2.cvtColor(BGRA, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGBA)
```